# NodeJs- How to use persian text in PdfKit module?

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, persian

This is my code :

```
 var doc = new PDFDocument();

 var stream = doc.pipe(blobStream());

 doc.fontSize(25)

     .text(سلام به همه', 100, 80');


 doc.end();

 stream.on('finish', function() {

     iframe.src = stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf');

 });
```

See image below :

[image]

PdfKit module has a problem with unicode.

How can I build **pdf** with **persian** character ?

Comment: Did you supply a supporting font? http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html#fonts It's going to be a font issue, it shouldn't be a PDFKit issue.

Comment: so you think that pdfkit support persian character ?